# AWS: authorizeSecurityGroupIngress within a VPC

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, node.js

I'm using the NodeJS SDK to add an inbound rule to a db security group from a db-access security group.

Both of these security groups exist within a VPC, however when I add the ingress rule using

```
params =
  GroupId: <Target Group Id>
  SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId: <Source Group Id>

ec2.authorizeSecurityGroupIngress(params, ...)
```

I get the following error: 
    `{ [MissingParameter: Source group ID missing.]
      message: 'Source group ID missing.',
      code: 'MissingParameter',
      time: Mon Nov 24 2014 19:44:13 GMT-0800 (PST),
      statusCode: 400,
      retryable: false,
      retryDelay: 30
    }`

The payload I'm sending has valid security groups, and when I look at the EC2 documentation, the only place where Source Group ID appears to come from is the *SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId* parameter.

Has anyone else run into this? Is this endpoint just flaky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation at:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#authorizeSecurityGroupIngress-property

it appears that you are using the function correctly. However, based on the name of the parameter `SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId`, I suspect that this may be the owner account ID of the security group you want to allow access, in cases where you want to permit cross-account access.

Instead, try using the `IpPermissions` array to indicate the security group information.

```
var params = {
  GroupId: <Target Group Id>,
  IpPermissions: [
    {
      IpProtocol: 'tcp',
      FromPort: <port>,
      ToPort: <port>,
      UserIdGroupPairs: [
        {
          GroupId: <Source Group Id>
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```